# Error While calling methods in main class

Tags: java

Here i'm trying to run a addition program of two numbers.
I have created three classes `student1`, `student2` and `example`. I am taking user input in both classes and want to add them, but unfortunately it is showing an error.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class student1
{
    public int sum()
    {
        int a;
        Scanner kb=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a number");
        a=kb.nextInt();
        return(a);

    }
}
class student2
{
    public int sum2()
    {
        int b;
        Scanner kb1=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter second number");
        b=kb1.nextInt();
        return(b);

    }
}
public class example
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        student1 o1=new student();
        o1.sum();
        student2 o2=new student2();
        o2.sum2();
        int c=a+b;
        System.out.println("Sum of " +a+ " and " +b+  " is " +c);
    }
}
```

I want this code to perform addition function of `a` and `b` while storing value into `c` and display the result.
Error: it is showing an error of **cannot find symbol**

Comment: I have downvoted this question because you have posted code on here without specifying what is wrong with it.  We expect to see what you expect the code to do, why you expect it to do this, what it is actually doing, and why it is wrong.  Please [edit] your question to include this information, and then I will consider retracting my downvote.  See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: i have edit the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your code to

```
    student1 o1=new student();
    int a = o1.sum();
    student2 o2=new student2();
    int b = o2.sum2();
    int c=a+b;
    System.out.println("Sum of " +a+ " and " +b+  " is " +c);
```

as you can not magically use the variables that are defined with other methods